# Can I use system error codes as user defined error codes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, error-handling

How can I know which constants apple allows to use them as user defined error codes.If the constant present in system error codes,still can I use it for my own purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on NSError. It is explicitly designed so you can define your own error domain and codes